# Silverstripe 4 How do I add a new custom group?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

How do I add a new user group?
Currently the only choices are **Administrators** and **Content Authors**.
 I want to add 2 new groups, one called **Customers** and **Technicians**, so that I can serve these logged in users custom pages.
I can't find clear direction in the documentation, however this page seems to be somewhat related to my question https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/security/member/

Comment: Just create them in the CMS?

Comment: This is a CMS user thing, unless you're asking about how to do it in code. The flow hasn't changed from SilverStripe 3 for this, so you might find the user guide helpful: https://userhelp.silverstripe.org/en/3.6/managing_your_website/managing_roles_and_permissions/#using-groups

Comment: Great thanks your right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create them in the cms.
Security->Groups->Add Group
After creating custom groups you can make pages in the cms and set to viewable to the custom group you've made. (notice Groups is at the top right of the Security menu)

[image]